# Double window controls - is this a known MS Word glitch on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

Required to reproduce:

- Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016
- Windows 10
- a 4K monitor

How to reproduce:

- open a document window
- if it's maximized, unmaximize to resizable mode
- drag the top edge of the window
- you will see a duplicate set of controls looking old-style

Note: this does not happen in Power Point, Excel, Visio. Is MS Word somehow differently integrated in the windowing system?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXh5l.jpg

Comment: Does that only happen the *drag-way*?

Comment: @Leun4m I consider, yes

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a glitch than a bug. Those controls are visible only briefly during dragging, aren't they? On my computer, this is not reproducible with Word 2016.

Technically, this is most likely related to way how window border is painted. Even if you have custom window border, it is painted on the top of standard one. It is possible that the result is visualized before finalization, this is what you see. You can try this also with other applications which use custom window borders, e.g. Skype or Slack.

Word can have some internals different from other Office apps, but at end of the day, end user is not affected by this so it is questionable whether it is worthy researching.

Comment: just for facts, I've tested this with Skype and Slack and neither of them has got this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Repairing Office May work:

Control Panel > Programs and Features > Office 20xx > Right-click & Repair

Answer (score 0):

Working IT in an enterprise environment I’ve had a lot of success using “OffCat” to find and resolve issues related to Office.

OffCat or Office Configuration is a Microsoft tool created and supported by 50 Microsoft Office engineers.

Downloadable from Microsoft 
[Microsoft OffCat](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36852)